# I have an error when I try to get target.value from MUI datepicker in Next.js

Tags: next.js, material-ui, datepicker

I am using MUI DatePicker. When I try to get target.value I have this error
[image]

Here is my code

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
  <DatePicker
    className={Turn.picker}
    defaultValue={date}
    InputProps={{ endAdornment: <CustomIconButton /> }}
    onChange={handleDateChange}
  />
</LocalizationProvider>
```

and this is my **hangleDataChange** function

```
const [date, setDate] = useState();
const handleDateChange = (event) => {
  setDate(event.target.value);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering is because the handleDateChange function is not receiving the expected event object.

Instead of event.target.value, you should be directly using the value provided by the onChange function of the DatePicker. The function should look like this:

```
const handleDateChange = (newValue) => {
  setDate(newValue);
};
```